# How can I have two desktop.ini files in the same place?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I just noticed that I have two `desktop.ini` files on my desktop. Why is this the case and how is this even possible? How does the computer know which desktop.ini I need to access if I try to open it via the command line?

[image]

File 1

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21769
IconResource=%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-183
```

File 2

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21799
```

Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What appears on your desktop is an amalgam of two folders, your personal desktop (`%USERPROFILE%\Desktop`) and the "All Users" desktop (`%PUBLIC%\Desktop`), and there is a `desktop.ini` in each.

If you right-click and examine the properties of each file, you will see the different locations.

Comment: Which is another windowism that doesn't make any sense at all. If you navigate using file explorer to your `C:\Users\name\Desktop` you only see **one** `desktop.ini`, so how can the actual desktop show both?